# Coil compose AsyncImage not working with images from TMDB api

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I'm using **TMDB api** which is a movie/tvShows api it provides a bunch of info about movies on of them is Poster `url` which consiste of just a path and you have to add a base url to it.
the problem is when i use this url for exemple:

```
http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/Af4bXE63pVsb2FtbW8uYIyPBadD.jpg
```

in Chrome or in PostMan it works perfectly it load the image and everything is good.
however when passing this `url` to coil `AsyncImage` it doesn't load anything, but if i use another dummy `url` from a random google image it load it without any problem:

With the TMBD image Url:

[image]

Random Google image url:

[image]

this the code I'm using to display images:

```
SubcomposeAsyncImage(
            model = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/Af4bXE63pVsb2FtbW8uYIyPBadD.jpg",
            contentDescription = "image",
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.25f)
                .fillMaxHeight(),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            loading = {
                CircularProgressIndicator()
            }
        )
```

is it a coil problem or the api itself or something im doig wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well after a day of debugging I found the problem!!

See the `URL` of **TMDB api** for images has a protocol of type `HTTP` but it turn out **Starting with Android 9 (API level 28)** Google has disabled support for non `HTTPS` `URL`, you can find more about this in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted).

Fortunatly the fix in this case is simple you just have to swap `Http` with `Https` in the `URL` and everything will work perfectly.